# How to join a Windows domain using Windows server?

Tags: windows-server-2008

How to join a Windows domain using Windows server? We wanted to add a server for Sharepoint, how do I join the domain of our DC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click Server Manager (NameOfServer) in the left pane of the Server Manager MMC, then click "Change System Properties" on the far-right.  In the dialog box that comes up, click the "Change" button next to where it says "to rename this computer or change its domain..."